# Google SignIn in iOS app without using UIViewController as Delegate

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-signin, gidsignin

Can we signIn using Google without setting UIViewcontroller as delegate? I've done the same thing in GooglePlus API, it seems not working now, throw exception..

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'

As many screens depends on google signIn, instead of adding signIn code everywhere I've created google manager singleton class and abstracted all the signIn logic. This class will give callback once signIn got success with access token. When I was using Google Plus API I was setting delegate like this...

```
signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
        signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES; // adds scope for "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
        signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES; // adds scope for "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
        signIn.clientID = kClientId;
        signIn.scopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login", @"profile", @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read"];
        signIn.delegate = self;
        signIn.attemptSSO = true;
```

And it worked as expected, now I've migrated to google signIn as google plus sign is deprecated,

```
gSignIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
gSignIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
gSignIn.clientID = kClientId;
gSignIn.scopes = @[ @"profile", @"email" ];
gSignIn.delegate = self;
gSignIn.uiDelegate = self;
[gSignIn signIn];
```

It is not allowing me to set singleton class as delegate, at run time it throws above exception.

Is it possible to set NSObject class as delegate in Google signIn? or Is there any workaround?